# Create function to slide div down and up all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to build a function that will slide down and up the specific div I'll mention later in the script, here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  div { background:yellow; border:1px solid #AAA; width:80px; height:80px; margin:0 5px; float:left; }
  div.colored { background:green; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="run">Run</button>

  <div></div>
  <div id="mover"></div>
  <div></div>
<script>

   $("button#run").click(function(){
    $("div:animated").toggleClass("colored");
   });

   function animateIt() {
    return $(this).slideToggle(5000, animateIt);
   }

    $("div#mover").animateIt();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But it gives me this error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'animateIt'"

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcQM7/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`animateIt` is not a jQuery method. Call it as a regular function, and pass in the element:

```
function animateIt ( $element ) {
   $element.slideToggle(5000, function (){
      animateIt($element);
   });
}

animateIt( $("div#mover") );​
```

Here's your fiddle, updated: http://jsfiddle.net/ZcQM7/2/

---

If you want it to be a jQuery method, you'll have to turn it into a plugin:

```
$.fn.animateIt = function () {
    var $this = this;
    this.slideToggle(5000, function () {
       $this.animateIt();
    });
};

$("div#mover").animateIt();​
```

Here's your fiddle again, with another update: http://jsfiddle.net/ZcQM7/1/

Answer (score 1):

`animateIt()` is a function that you declared in your code and does not belong to jQuery.

You should call it directly:

```
function animateIt() {
   return $("#mover").slideToggle(5000, animateIt);
}

animateIt();
```